# How to get the average of my 5 columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get the average score of my 5 columns and insert the result in the average. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
if(!$con) {
    die('not connected');
}
$con = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM scoreboard");

?>
<center>
  <div>
    <center><td><h2>View Score</h2></td></center>
    <table border="2">
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>VALUE 1</th>
        <th>VALUE 2</th>
        <th>VALUE 3</th>
        <th>VALUE 4</th>
        <th>VALUE 5</th>
        <th>AVERAGE SCORE</th>
      </tr>
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con)) {

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score3']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score4'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score5'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['average'] ;?></td>
      </tr>
<?php

}

?>
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Add them all up then divide by 5. This also looks like a bad DB scheme.

Comment: you don't have to put it in the database, you can just make it a **derived** attribute.

Comment: Sorry. I will change it

Comment: @user8388243 : If you provide your table `schema` that will be easier to understand, whether you can achieve via `built-in` functions or you have to use `php`.

Comment: I want to get the average score of the value1, value2,value3,value4,value5 then the result is will insert in my average row

Comment: @user8388243 : value1, value2..etc are these columns? or rows with 2 column, I hope you are able to understand what I am asking for.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You're missing `<tr>` before the `<th>` row. You have `<td>` on the previous line that isn't part of a table.

Comment: Columns sir, sorry sir  im wrong

Comment: ... what is going on in your HTML there my man? What is the resulting HTML of this? i.e. what is output to the browser?

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the average with simple arithmetic:

```
$average = ($row['score1'] + $row['score2'] + $row['score3'] + $row['score4'] + $row['score5'])/5;
```

Or you can do it in the SQL:

```
SELECT *, (score1+score2+score3+score4+score5)/5 AS average FROM scoreboard
```

Comment: How can i fix it

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with my calculation. Can you show some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: HOW CAN YOU SAY THAT `average` sore was wrong with this query. this query will output the exact average. Show sample data

Comment: This is my 2+3+1/3 the average score show was 2.0000

Comment: that's not avg.It's only sum:- https://eval.in/869974  . there is big difference between avg and sum

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you gonna have only 5 values which you need to sum out and take the average.

If that's the case, I will prefer to take average in php rather than using mysql and increase query time.

```
$average = ($row['score1'] + $row['score2'] + $row['score3'] + $row['score4'] + $row['score5'])/5;
```

then

```
<td><?php echo $average ;?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$average = ($row['score1'] + $row['score2'] + $row['score3'] + $row['score4'] + $row['score5']) /5;


<td><?php echo $average ;?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)) {

$average = ($row['score1'] + $row['score2'] + $row['score3'] + $row['score4'] + $row['score5'])/5;

?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score1']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score3']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score4'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['score5'] ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $average; ?> </td>
      </tr>
<?php

}
?>
```

You should try this.And you need to do one more change.

```
$con = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM scoreboard");
```

change the variable name.

```
$exe = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM scoreboard");
```